# Issues accessing Facebook profile image

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, titanium

This is the kind of question that I am sure has a simple answer, but I been with this for days now without finding it.

The issue comes when I try to access the `picture` via the graph API.

According to the graph API the following URL should return a JSON with `is_silhouette` and `url`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture
```

When I try that in the `Graph Explorer` it works fine, but when I test the same URL in the browser I get automatically redirected to the URL attribute of the response instead of getting a JSON.

My problem is that I need to access the contents of that JSON to get the URL attribute in order to display the user profile.

My code looks something like this

```
var fbimage = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + e.uid + "/picture/";
    var xhrFbImage = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function() {
            jsonData = '';
            jsonData = this.responseText;
            Ti.API.info("inside FB response...");
            Ti.API.info(jsonData);
        }
    });
    xhrFbImage.open("GET", getFbImage);
    xhrFbImage.send();
```

The response is always `null`

Any tip in the right direction will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

By adding `?redirect=false` I get the actual JSON without the redirect.

So the correct URL to query is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture?redirect=false
```

The answer was more visible than I thought. You can refer to it here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/